# How to add delete in php script in my photo gallery

Tags: php, html, photo, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I made a Photo gallery by php.
I am able to make upload image and show the image list. But i want to add a delete button where users can delete there unwanted image. But i was failed to add this button work.

Someone please help to fix it?

Here is my code on GitHub: https://github.com/sagar290/photo_gallerey/blob/6cad3743e735ea109723de7e14d5477bff1e964b/gallery.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
  $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  //$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
  //$extention = $type;
  $type = strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']);
  $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


  if (isset($name)) {
    if (!empty($name)) {
      if (($type=='image/jpg')||($type=='image/jpeg')||($type=='image/gif')) {
        $location = 'photos/';

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, 'photos/'.$name)) {
          echo $name.' is uploaded';

        }
      }else {
        echo 'file must be jpg or jpeg ';
      }


    }else {
      echo 'please choose a file';
    }
  }
}

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Photo gallery</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        ul {
          list-style-type: none;
        }
      li {
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        font: bold 10px Verdana, sans-serif;
      }
      img {
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid #333300;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Photo gallery</h2>

      <form action="gallery.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      UPLOAD:
      <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

      <ul>
        <form action="gallery.php" method="POST">
<?php


    //define location of photo image
    $photosDir = './photos';

    //define which file extention are images
    $photosExt = array('gif','jpg','jpeg','tif','tiff','bmp','png');

    //initialize array to hold filenames of images found
    $photoList = array();

    //read directory contents
    //build photo list
    if (file_exists($photosDir)) {
      $dp = opendir($photosDir) or die('Error: cannot open file');
      while ($file =  readdir($dp)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
          $fileData = pathinfo($file);
          if (in_array($fileData['extension'], $photosExt)) {
            $photoList[] = "$photosDir/$file"; // file includes as an array
          }
        }
      }
      closedir($dp);
    }else {
      die('ERROR: directory dosent exists');
    }

    //itarate over photo list
    //display each image and file name
    if (count($photoList)>0) {
      for ($x=0; $x <count($photoList) ; $x++) {
        ?>

        <li>
          <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
          <img src="<?php echo $photoList[$x]; ?>" height="150" width="200"/>
          <?php echo basename($photoList[$x]); ?><br>
          <?php echo round(filesize($photoList[$x])/1024) . 'KB'; ?>
        </li>

        <?php
      }
    } else {
      die('ERROR: No image found');
    }





?>

    </form>
  </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see any code in there that attempts to delete an image

Comment: `<li>
          <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
          <img src="<?php echo $photoList[$x]; ?>" height="150" width="200"/>
          <?php echo basename($photoList[$x]); ?><br>
          <?php echo round(filesize($photoList[$x])/1024) . 'KB'; ?>
        </li>` this code looping the photo from the directory. so i want to delete specific image which i want to, but i cant make that delete function.

Comment: I see. It doesn't tell PHP which image to delete. Someone has provided an answer anyway

Comment: yah but still not working.  cant delete image. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello just change your submit input to:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="<?php echo $photoList[$x] ?>">
```

and then check for that value:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['delete']) && !empty($_POST['delete'])){
    //find the file
    $file = 'photos/'.$_POST['delete'];
    if(is_file($file)){
        unlink($file);
    }else{
        echo $_POST['delete']." has not been found!";
    }
}?>
```

Comment: You're missing all the single quotes.

Comment: The delete button is input:submit, as are the others. Are you sure that is the only variable with name of delete that gets posted when clicked?